# How to solve $\frac{1}{2^x+3} \geq \frac{1}{2^{x+2}-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponentiation

I guess it's easy, but I still need help. The inequality is
$$\frac{1}{2^x+3} \geq \frac{1}{2^{x+2}-1}$$
If you set $t=2^x$, then it becomes
$$\frac{1}{t+3} \geq \frac{1}{4t-1}$$

---

The set of solutions is
$$x \in (-\infty,-2) \cup \{1\}$$
which is not what I get.

---

*My attempt*

$$\frac{1}{2^x+3} \geq \frac{1}{2^{x+2}-1}$$
This is undefined for $x=-2$, because the right hand side becomes: $\frac{1}{2^{-2+2}-1}=\frac{1}{2^0-1}=\frac{1}{1-1}=\frac{1}{0}$. Therefore,
$$x \neq -2$$
Now, let's set $t=2^x$.
$$\frac{1}{t+3} \geq \frac{1}{4t-1}$$
Multiply both sides with $(t+3)(4t-1)$.
We must split the inequality because we don't know is $(t+3)(4t-1)$ positive or negative. *Question: what if it's zero? Should we consider that possibility too?*

For $(t+3)(4t-1) > 0$:
$$4t-1 \geq t+3$$
$$3t \geq 4$$
$$t \geq \frac{4}{3}$$
$$2^x \geq \frac{4}{3}$$
$$x \geq \log_2 \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$$

For $(t+3)(4t-1) < 0$:
$$4t-1 \leq t+3$$
$$3t \leq 4$$
$$t \leq \frac{4}{3}$$
$$2^x \leq \frac{4}{3}$$
$$x \leq \log_2 \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$$

I think it's already obvious where and how I'm wrong, so I think I don't need to continue with this attempt. If I do, then please ask in the comment.

Comment: Please include your efforts. Then we can say, where you are mistaken. Maybe it is just a small step. Did you consider that the direction of the inequality changes if you multiply the equation with a negative value? Hence, if you multiply the equation with $4t-1$ you have to consider the cases $t>\frac14$ and $t<\frac14$.

Comment: Multiply the equation with $(t+3)(4t-1)$. If this expression is positive, the $\ge$-sign does not change, if it is negative, it changes to $\le$

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Yes, I did consider that. I don't have a paper where I tried to solve this right now, so I'll try to do that again. It'll take some time, but when I'm done I'll edit the question to include my attempt.

Comment: This solution set **cannot be right**. $x=1$ corresponds to $1/5\ge1/7$ and by continuity nearby values will also do.

Comment: "The comment you have to ask me about"

Comment: @AsafKaragila ???

Comment: I'm just reflecting your title. How about giving this a proper title?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, much better. Thanks.

Comment: Don't cross-multiply with inequalities; for example, ${}^1/{}_2>{}^1/{}_3$ but when you cross-multiply, you get $3>2$ which is false. First, try to get $0$ as the subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continue from your efforts, $2^x = t$ already implies $t \gt 0$.
 $$\frac{1}{t+3}- \frac{1}{4t-1} \ge 0\\
 \frac{3t-4}{(t+3)(4t-1)}\ge 0$$

Solving this inequality with the help of zero points of the three factors, gives $t\in (-3,1/4) \cup [4/3, \infty) $ but we also had $t\gt 0$. So final answer is $t \in (0,1/4) \cup [4/3, \infty)$.

So $x \in (-\infty, -2) \cup [2-\log_2(3), \infty)$

Comment: Can you please add how do you go from $t \in (0,1/4) \cup [4/3,\infty)$ to $x \in (-\infty,-2) \cup (2-\log_2(3),\infty)$.

Comment: @Vuk hmm $\log_2(x)$ is increasing. So if $0\lt2^x\lt 1/4$ then $\log_2(0^+)\lt x \lt \log_2(1/4)$. Similarly for other inequality..

Comment: You can safely use $t+3>0$, which simplifies the discussion.

Comment: @Yves oh yeah good point

Comment: @samjoe I don't understand one thing. When converting the intervals of $t$ to the intervals of $x$ you converted $t=0$ to $x=-\infty$. How?

Comment: As $t\to -\infty$, $2^{x} \to 0^+$

Answer (score 4):

The given solution is clearly wrong on the positive side. For instance, take $x=2$, and 
$$
\frac17=\frac{1}{2^x+3}\geq\frac{1}{2^{x+2}-1}=\frac1{15}.
$$

Since $t=2^x$ you know that $t>0$. So $t+3>0$. Now if $4t-1>0$, everything is positive and you can multiply to get 
$$
4t-1\geq t+3,
$$
which simplifies to $3t\geq4$, or $t\geq4/3$.

If, on the other hand, $4t-1<0$, the inequality will be reversed if we multiply by it. So we get 
$$
4t-1\leq t+3,
$$
which is $t\leq 4/3$. This was under the hypothesis $t<1/4$, so we get $t<1/4$.

In summary, the inequality holds when $t<1/4$ and when $t\geq 4/3$.

Now we translate to $x$. The equality $2^x=1/4$ gives $x=-2$. The equality $2^x=4/3$, gives $x=\log_24-\log_23=2-\log_23$. So the inequality holds for 
$$
x\in(-\infty,-2)\cup[2-\log_23,\infty)
$$

Comment: The second interval should be closed.

Comment: Indeed. Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that $t>0$, the LHS is non-negative and the inequation certainly holds for $$t\lt\frac14.$$
Then for $t>\dfrac14$, the RHS is also non-negative and we need

$$t+3\le4t-1$$ or

$$t\ge\frac43.$$

Hence

$$x<\log_2\frac14\lor x\ge \log_2\frac43.$$